# Laravel: Reset password using the username

Tags: php, laravel

I need to be able to reset a users password based on their username rather than their email address. The database does store the email address, but a user can have multiple user accounts with the same email address. Therefore, the username is the best unique factor to reset the password on.

My current password reset request is:

```
switch (Password::remind(Input::only('email')))
{
  case Password::INVALID_USER:
    return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($reason));

  case Password::REMINDER_SENT:
    return Redirect::back()->with('status', Lang::get($reason));
}
```

My current reset function is

```
$credentials = Input::only(
    'username', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
);

$response = Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password){
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);

    $user->save();
});

switch ($response){
    case Password::INVALID_PASSWORD:
    case Password::INVALID_TOKEN:
    case Password::INVALID_USER:
    return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));

    case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
    return Redirect::to('/overview');
}
```

I know changing the Password::remind and Password:reset function use send the username won't resolve things. I just don't know how to tell it to use the username column instead of the email column.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @tamaghna-banerjee login is different from forgot password.